# Chords not waiting for all child tasks

Tags: celery

I have a few tasks like this:

```
@celery.task
def generate():
    sleep(1.0)
    print "Generate done!"
    return 'result'

@celery.task
def lower(result):
    sleep(1.0)
    print "Lower done!"
    return result.lower()

@celery.task
def upper(result):
    sleep(1.0)
    print "Upper done!"
    return result.upper()

@celery.task
def upload(result):
    sleep(1.0)
    print "Upload done for: %s!" % (result,)
    return 'upload'

@celery.task
def callback(results):
    print "It's all done! %s" % (results,)
```

I'm creating a chord that looks like this:

```
chord(
    header=chain(
        generate.s(),
        group(
            chain(lower.s(), upload.s()),
            chain(upper.s(), upload.s())
        )
    ), body=callback.s()
).delay()
```

The problem that I'm experiencing is that my callback, which is supposed to fire after all tasks have been completed, seems to fire right after `generate`.

In case it's not clear, the workflow is like this:

1. Generate a result, then pass its result onto members of a group, so as to achieve parallelism:

   1. Group one will take the result from `generate`, convert it to lowercase using `lower`, and then upload the result using `upload`.
   2. Group two will take the result from `generate`, convert it to uppercase using `upper`, and then upload the result using `upload'.
2. After all of this is done, the `callback` task callback should be called.

#### Expected

The `callback` task will be called at least 3 seconds after starting.

#### Actual

The `callback` task is called around 1 second after starting, and does not wait for members of the group to finish executing.

Here are the logs proving that it doesn't wait for groups:

```
[2013-11-17 18:20:40,447: WARNING/PoolWorker-8] Generate done!
[2013-11-17 18:20:41,493: WARNING/PoolWorker-6] Upper done!
[2013-11-17 18:20:41,493: WARNING/PoolWorker-1] Lower done!
[2013-11-17 18:20:41,535: WARNING/PoolWorker-6] It's all done! [('e0016a35-d538-4e96-ad86-6ddf91ef4a09', [('b1af78a9-7935-4037-84e4-9fae6d7c027e', None), ('d69c4c99-af9c-476f-af7d-7f647c4d9c83', None)])]
[2013-11-17 18:20:42,522: WARNING/PoolWorker-7] Upload done for: result!
[2013-11-17 18:20:42,523: WARNING/PoolWorker-5] Upload done for: RESULT!
```

It seems that Celery doesn't wait on groups. Is there a way to have Celery wait until ALL tasks, including members of groups, are finished executing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using a chain as the chord header here, but the header must be a group:

```
chord(
    header=chain(
        generate.s(),
        group(
            chain(lower.s(), upload.s()),
            chain(upper.s(), upload.s())
        )
    ), body=callback.s()
).delay()
```

With `chain(generate.s(), group(...)` there is nothing to synchronize with as the
group happens in parallel.

Your workflow could better be expressed like this:

```
filters = group(lower.s() | upload.s(),
                upper.s() | upload.s())
result = (generate.s() | filters | callback.s())()
```

Note: `chain(group, sig)` is automatically converted to chord

Comment: The only reason I haven't just used a chain until this point is that I need a callback that will _always_ fire, as my `callback` task does cleanup and reporting on what worked and what didn't. With your example above, will the `callback` always be triggered?